# avatar com informações do usuario

Tags: php, mysql

É o seguinte pessoal, talvez isso seja bem básico, mas como eu faço pra associar a imagem de uma pasta imagens por exemplo ao usuário de id 1 no banco? O usuario 1 terá a imagem 01 da pasta img? Me recomendariam criar o "caminho da pasta" com o nome da imagem no banco e criar uma relação com a tabela usuarios? Ou tem outras técnicas mais uteis e usadas atualmente para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma coluna na tabela de usuários para armazenar o caminho do avatar de acordo com sua estrutura:

```
ID NOME  AVATAR
1  Asura img/avatares/123456.jog
```

Agora sempre que tiver o registro do usuário você terá o caminho da imagem para carregar:

```
<img src="<?php echo $usuario->avatar;?> />
```

Acho essa maneira interessante porque você pode separar as imagens por contexto, vamos supor que você tenha a tabela `produtos`, você pode criar o diretório `img/produtos` e na hora de salvar o produto, você coloca o caminho da imagem no registro ou até mesmo em outra tabela, caso o produto tenha mais de uma imagem.

Comment: Só uma pergunta, não sei se pode, mas você sabe como eu faria pra cada usuario ter mais de uma imagem relacionada? E muito obrigado!

Comment: @AsuraKhan Nesse caso você deve criar uma tabela para armazenar os caminhos. Uma tabela por exemplo, `UsuariosAvatares` com as colunas `id`, `usuario_id` e `avatar`. É possível também, caso você tenha um limite de duas imagens, por exemplo, usar um separador no registro: `img/avatares/123.jpg;img/avatares/321.png` assim você só faria um `split()` no `;` e teria um `array` com os caminhos das imagens.

Comment: Caraka, perfeito! Tinha esquecido completamente do Split. E você disse que eu tria que criar esse "img/avatares/123456.jpg", esse 123456 seria o id? Ou pode ser um numero randômico?

Comment: @AsuraKhan Pode ser o nome da imagem ou qualquer coisa que você achar interessante. Eu gosto de colocar `timestamp` assim eu não corro risco de ter imagens com nomes duplicados e acabar sobrescrevendo uma delas. Desse modo seria algo do tipo `img/avatares/17072015150955.jpg`

Comment: Então quando realizar o upload da imagem na pasta, eu também adiciono o caminho no banco em um cadastro normal com id e as informações?

Comment: @AsuraKhan Exato =)